# Combine string from two rows into new column

Tags: mysql

I have a database with two rows of data. I want to combine a column from the previous row and one from the current row to create the COMBINED column. (I also want to somehow format the FORMATTED column to auto-lowercase the first letter of the RAW string unless it is "I", remove the punctuation, and add a period to the end).

```
RAW..............|..FORMATTED..........|.....COMBINED<br>
I have a cold.|..When I have a cold..| <br>
I get sniffly.....|..When I get sniffly,....|......When I have a cold, I get sniffly.
```

How might I make SQL create the desired data in the COMBINED column of the most recent row (i.e. "When I have a cold, I get sniffly")? I have only managed to combine two columns of data using 
SELECT CONCAT('formatted', 'raw') FROM 'table' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 (but obviously this gave me "When I get sniffly, I get sniffly." - I need 'formatted' from the penultimate row, and 'raw' from the most recent row.

Any help would be appreciated, with either question.

Comment: Not possible, because every "next" row is not Aware of any previous row. You can Combine columns WITHIN ONE ROW, but not accross multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Im very sorry, I tried this, It's a very brute force way, but it might work.

```
SELECT CONCAT((SELECT formatted 
               FROM 'table' 
               ORDER BY id 
               DESC LIMIT 1),
              (SELECT raw
               FROM 'table' 
               ORDER BY id 
               DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2));
```

When it works, write a STORED PROCEDURE, loop this QUERY and KEEP the limit and offset values as i and i+1.

Or, dump the data to a text file and use ruby!

Comment: Thank you both. I couldn't get your method to work, Beck (I'm brand new at this), so I just kept the columns separate and echoed them side by side on my page through php (which is the result I wanted, anyway).